# npm run build gives 404 on Shopify app development

Tags: npm, shopify, shopify-app

I have created a new app using the Shopify App Template for PHP (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-php).

When I run `npm run dev` the app works fine in my local development environment.

However, when I try to deploy the app to a server and run `npm run build --api-key=MY_API_KEY` I encounter the following error:

*"Building the frontend app without an API key. The frontend build will not run without an API key. Set the SHOPIFY_API_KEY environment variable when running the build command."*

To resolve this issue, I tried running the build command with the environment variable set as follows:
`SHOPIFY_API_KEY=MY_API_KEY npm run build`

This successfully addressed the API key error.

However, now when I attempt to install my app on a development store, the installation flow redirects to the React page I built, but then redirects back to Shopify with a 404 error. It seems that the authentication, app installation, and recurring charge steps are being missed.

Can you please help what am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the existence of index.html in the public directory after running `composer build` in the web directory.

in your nginx/apache config you probably have something like
`index index.html index.htm index.php;`

change this to be in alignment with the recommendation from the supplied nginx.conf in the repository.

`index index.php index.html index.htm;`